# Can we wrap non react functions with 4Catalyzer/found's 'withRouter' HOC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, higher-order-functions

this is the code im trying to run:

```
import { withRouter } from 'found';

const routeToUrl = props => props.router.push(props.path);

export default withRouter(routeToUrl);
```

where withRouter is HOC from `catalyzer/found` wraps an existing component class or function and injects `match` and `router` props, as on route components above. You can use this HOC to create components that navigate programmatically in event handlers.  https://github.com/4Catalyzer/found#programmatic-navigation

I'm a little unclear on the meaning of `route components`. Is `routeToUrl` not being a route component the reason this is not working?

error received:

```
react.development.js?99ee:428 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined
    at Component (react.development.js?99ee:428)
    at withRouter(routeToUrl) (connectAdvanced.js?4805:109)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

withRouter needs Router in upper context

Are you need Redirect component or just need to use location.path ?

Comment: i need to programmatically navigate on certain conditions to `path` argument passed in. I intend to call this `routeToUrl('${window.location.pathname}?${search.toString()}')`